# Handling links in my application

Tags: android, url, browser, browsable

I want handle this `URL` but my code is not work true.

> http://melkplus.com/#!/property/details/765

Actually when I click on this `URL`, my phone does not suggest me my application and it just open by browser.

I think application has problem with #! in `URL`.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data
    android:host="melkplus.com"
    android:scheme="http"
    android:pathPrefix="/#!/property/details/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything starting with the `#` is not part of the path of the URL, but rather is the fragment. You cannot filter on fragments.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: @RuhallahAhmadian: Replace `android:pathPrefix="/#!/property/details/"` with `android:pathPrefix="/"`.

Comment: but if I have another link, I can not open it.

Comment: @RuhallahAhmadian: I do not know what "another link" is.

Comment: @RuhallahAhmadian: That also matches `android:pathPrefix="/"`, and so your activity will handle both URLs. If you are saying that you want a *separate* activity to handle those two, you should be able to replace `android:pathPrefix="/#!/property/details/"` with `android:path="/"`, so the activity in your question only matches on `/`. Other activities could then match on other things (e.g., a prefix of `/agency`).